# how to parse solr suggester component json response in ajax autocomplete?

Tags: json, solr

hello i am trying parse solr suggester query output in search box but not getting exact result. plz help...........

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $( "#searchterm" ).autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    var text = $("#searchterm").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/suggest?wt=json&indent=true&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.q='+request.term+'&spellcheck.onlyMorePopular=true&spellcheck.count=50&start=0&rows=10',
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        jsonp: 'json.wrf',
                        type:'GET',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        success: function(data) {
                            response( $.map(data.spellcheck.suggestions, function(item,i) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.suggestion,
                                    value: item.suggestion
                                }                                             
                            }));
                        }                      
                    });
```

Comment: What problem do you exactly have? Try to log data to debug the return value from Solr.

Comment: I am not able to print result in search box.. Here is my result

Comment: use console.log(data) in the success callback

Comment: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1},
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[
      "ajax",{
        "numFound":1,
        "startOffset":0,
        "endOffset":4,
        "suggestion":["ajaxs"]},
      "sup",{
        "numFound":10,
        "startOffset":5,
        "endOffset":8,
        "suggestion":["super",
          "supercoppa",
          "supercup",
          "superleague",
          "superstar",
          "supervisor",
          "supoporter",
          "suporter",
          "suporters",
          "supusepa"]}]}}  how to print it since it does not have key value pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing the console.log of data your iterated elements value is

```
"[ "ajax",{ "numFound":1, "startOffset":0, "endOffset":4, "suggestion":["ajaxs"]}, "sup",{ "numFound":10, "startOffset":5, "endOffset":8, "suggestion":["super", "supercoppa", "supercup", "superleague", "superstar", "supervisor", "supoporter", "suporter", "suporters", "supusepa"]}]"
```

You have to work on level deeper on suggestions.suggestion